# Can the composition of a continuous and a discontinuous function be continuous?

Tags: functions

Let $I$ be an interval in $\Bbb{R}$ and $f, g : I\to \Bbb{R}$ such that $f$ is continuous and $g$ is discontinuous.

Question: Can either of $f\circ g$ or $g\circ f$ be continuous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Take $I=\mathbb{R}$, $f\equiv 0$, $g$ is Dirichlet function. Both $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are continuous in that case.

Comment: You should briefly recall what Dirichlet function is...

Comment: This is a very known function. It is $1_{\mathbb{Q}}$.

Comment: As a teacher, I think that it is always good to recap important things (self contained content) especially when you have room, whence my remark. Moreover, it is a "very well known function" for analysts but not especialy for the "vulgus pecus".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example.

Take

- for function $f$ the **continuous** "absolute value" function,
- for function $g$ the **discontinuous** function (curve represented in red on the figure below) defined by :

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}-x-1&\text{if} \ -1 \leq x < 0\\
-x+1&\text{if} \ \ \ 0 \leq x \leq 1\\
0&\text{elsewhere}\\
\end{cases} ;$$

$g$ is a **discontinuous** function .

Then

> $$(f \circ g)(x)=(g \circ f)(x)=t(x)$$

where $t$ is the **continuous** so-called "tent" function (blue curve on the figure).

[image]

Similar question : [Composition of a continuous function and a discontinuous function, can be continous.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1655958).